# TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of null

Tags: node.js, discord.js

For some reason, every time I run a command or send a message in one of the channels I've specified in my index file, the console spits out the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of null`.

Here's the code:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
  let schannel = message.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === "suggestions");
  if(message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) return
  else if(!schannel) return console.log(`There is no suggestions channel!`);;
  if (message.channel != schannel || message.author.bot || message.content.startsWith("!suggest")) return;
  else message.delete().catch(O_o=> {});
});
```

Comment: Maybe you need to check if the guild is available for data transfer with `guild.available` (according to https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild)

Comment: This is thrown on the second line? `let schannel`?

Answer (score 1):

I would try checking the guild before you ask for the `.channel` collection.

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
  let guild = message.guild;
  if (!guild || !guild.avilable) return console.log("The guild is not availbale.");
  // rest of the code here...
});
```

Comment: It says the guild is not available, what does that mean?

Comment: It means that either the message is a DM (and so has no guild) or that the message comes from a guild that is in a server outage